# Exception Handler not working in a spring boot app with messaging

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, messaging

I've seen many a posts and Q&As on StackOverflow for custom error handling for a REST/MVC applications.

My situation is slightly different though. My application uses Java Messaging (with ActiveMQ and SpringIntegration) and 
the method below is triggered as a response to a JMessage:

```
public BenefitVersion getVersionAt(LocalDate referenceDate) {
    return versions.stream()
            .filter(benefitVersion -> !benefitVersion.getStartDate().isAfter(referenceDate))
            .reduce(maxBy(getBenefitVersionStartDateComparator()
                    .thenComparingLong(BenefitVersion::getId)))
            .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalBenefitVersionException(guid,
                    format("Benefit %s does not have active version on %s", guid, referenceDate)));
}
```

I've defined custom exception as below:

```
public class IllegalBenefitVersionException extends RuntimeException {
    private UUID benefitId;

public IllegalBenefitVersionException(final UUID benefitId, final String message) {
    super(message);
    this.benefitId = benefitId;
    }
}
```

And a custom handler for that exception:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class IllegalBenefitVersionExceptionHandler {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(IllegalBenefitVersionExceptionHandler.class);
private final DlqExceptionDetailService exceptionDetailService;

@Autowired
public IllegalBenefitVersionExceptionHandler(DlqExceptionDetailService exceptionDetailService) {
    this.exceptionDetailService = exceptionDetailService;
}

@ExceptionHandler(IllegalBenefitVersionException.class)
public void handleException(Throwable t) {
    IllegalBenefitVersionException exception = (IllegalBenefitVersionException) t;
    exceptionDetailService.newWithBenefitIdAndSave(exception.getBenefitId(), t.getMessage());
    LOGGER.error("From ExceptionHandler: {}", t.getMessage(), t);
}
```

}

But that never gets called. Is the reason because I use the `@ControllerAdvice` whereas there is no controller?

Or perhaps I need to add special component scan somewhere?

If so, how do I wire up a custom exception handler in a messaging-based, as opposed to, REST, application?

Comment: You are correct about why your advice is not applied; you're not using a controller. Please provide more detail about how exactly you're consuming messages: Spring Integration? Spring Cloud Stream? Manual wiring?

Comment: I use SpringIntegration, thanks!